# Similarities and differences between exponential function and polynomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials, exponential-function

I have searched online for this answer, but the only difference I have found is that an exponential function is to the power of x, while a polynomial function is x to the power of something. I did not find any similarities.

Does anyone know of any additional similarities or differences?

Comment: Well, this is a stretch, but...
$$e^x=\frac{x^0}{0!}+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE: Please use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: We generally restrict ourselves to polynomials of finite degree. If we allow polynomials of infinite degree (or the ones that converge, at least), then many functions, including all exponential functions are "polynomials".

Comment: You may be interested  to know that $e^x$ is the limit of $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ as n goes to infinity.